# I want to implement a function which will check any changes made by any user in the sql server and send notification to the admin

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing an online system in which there are 20 user and each user have permission to change the SQL server data with respect to their roles, and admin can see all the data of all user's. I want to highlight that specific data which is changed by the user in the time period, when admin last time login and check notification. I am using ASP.net MVC with SQL Server and entity framework.

Comment: OK, I'll get started.  When do you need this by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are millions way to solve this issue. One of them is to create an Audit table so you can track "who" did it "when" he/she did it and "what" was changed.

You can architect it to be per field or store all data before and after (for example, using nvarchar(max) and JSON). It is really hard to tell which one is better in your case, cause it is a task specific question.

So it could be done like that:

```
Id | Object/Id | Operation/Id | User/Id | DateTime | FieldName/id | Previous Value | New Value

1 | Prices Table | Add    | John Dow | 2017-10-09 13:21 | Discount Price | null | $200 
2 | Prices Table | Update | John Dow | 2017-10-09 14:21 | Discount Price | $200 | $210
```

So you will be able to tell who changed DiscountPrice field in the Prices table between 13:00 and 15:00. I highly recommend to use Ids, not real values so it will be efficient from space and a search perspective. I used real values just to highlight my idea.

Something like that. I hope it helps. Good luck!